# Unupvote after many days, no edits were made in the meantime

Tags: discussion, up-votes

I've just been dinged for an upvote reverse on [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235906/how-do-i-fix-this-bad-bending-in-my-minecraft-arm/237158#237158) as witnessed by this summary

[image: -10 charge on question]

Earlier, the downvote showed in the time line and I've had the points deducted from my reputation but now it's not:

[image: vote reversal not showing on time line]

Does anybody know what happened / is happening?

Comment: I don't have an answer for this, only maybe an admin will know. My only possible explanation is that either the rep recalc happened at a later time then the unupvote, or the vote was not yet locked for some unknown reason

Comment: Both the vote reversal and the rep recalculation happened yesterday, more than month after the last edit.  Can you confirm that the vote should have been locked after that much time?  (I'm suspecting that this is a bug somehow, and I want to be very sure before I take it to meta.)

Comment: "*Can you confirm that the vote should have been locked after that much time?*" No, I can't confirm that. It is supposed to be in the order of minutes as far as I know, but I don't know how many, nor if there are other circumstances where it can be extended for one reason or another

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I'll just report it on meta as a bug and see what happens.

Comment: I don't think it is a bug, but let me know what comes of it. Or share a link so I can follow it, I'm curious as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this on [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) as a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370860/is-this-unexpected-upvote-reversal-evidence-of-a-bug-or-just-serial-upvote-rever) and the answer is that

1. The vote disappearing from the answer's timeline display is not a bug, but

> It might be confusing but I guess it's [status-bydesign](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

2. From a comment on the accepted answer, paraphrased, votes are unlocked by an edit and never relocked until they are changed again.

So the conclusion is "not a bug".